# why is `tox` installing packages in system Python directory in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, tox

I am new to `tox`, but my understanding is that it creates local virtual environments for each testing environment. However, it seems whenever I run `tox` it first installs the package to the system Python installation and then installs any dependencies there too.

Here is the simplest example I can show:

My `tox.ini` is simply:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27

[testenv]
commands = pytest

deps =
    pytest
```

Then the following series of commands show `pytest` is not installed, but at the end of the `tox` run, it is installed in the system python path:

```
> which pytest
which: no pytest in (/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86....

> tox
[... lots of output ...]

___________________________________ summary ___________________________________
  py27: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

Then,

```
> which pytest
/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/pytest
```

Additionally, I see the package I'm testing is also installed in the system python directory.

Shouldn't `tox` be generating a virtual environment locally? I see there is a `.tox/py27` directory that gets created, but it looks like a Linux-style installation with a `bin` directory instead of `Scripts`. Is this the expected behavior of `tox`?

Comment: Hi Rich, that's an interesting one. 

This is likely an unexpected interaction between tox and cygwin. tox is not officially supporting (or even aware of) Windows + Cygwin and it should actually use the proper path for your Windows install (`C:\Python27` and not `/cygdrive/c/Python27`).

The second surprise is that tox really does not create a virtualenv but uses the original interpreter. I have no idea how this is even possible - especially with a simple `tox.ini` like you posted. So I am really stumped here.

Comment: Could you please open an issue with the tox project (https://github.com/tox-dev/tox) and describe the problem in detail there? Especially if you have done any extra setup regarding paths and Cygwin? Thanks. 

Looking at tox interaction with cygwin in the issues there is nothing related yet: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cygwin+ - so this will need some investigation.

Comment: Uhhh I don't think this has anything to do with Tox.  You shouldn't be calling a Windows Python from Cygwin in the first place and should remove it from your `PATH`, or at least ensure that your Cygwin `/bin` paths are first on the `PATH`.  Otherwise don't use Cygwin.

Comment: Hi @oliver-bestwalter, I realize it's confusing to have put the output of my `which` statement there. I wasn't actually running that in a Cygwin shell, but it does so happen that Cygwin utilities are in my path. I removed Cygwin from my path and can verify that is what seems to be causing `tox` to think it is in a Linxu environment, but I don't understand why that would be unless `tox` were attempting some system commands, no? I'll post a report over at `git` as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Iguananaut, for reference, I wasn't in a Cygwin shell to run Python, but Cygwin utilities are in my path. But I did bump the Cygwin to the front of my path which solved my issue. I'm not sure why since the only two elements before Cygwin were TortoiseHG and TortoiseSVN. I'd love to know why this worked. If you'd like to post this as the answer for the "rep" I'm happy to mark it so.

Comment: Well that would do it!  Mercurial is written in Python, so TortoiseHG probably has its own python.exe in there (I'm not sure why Tortoise even needs to be on PATH, but that's another question....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you wound up with a Windows-native Python on your system's `PATH` environment variable that is being inserted somehow even before Cygwin's `/bin` paths, so `tox` is finding and trying to run that Python instead of Cygwin's Python.  In general you shouldn't use the Windows Python from Cygwin unless there's a very specific reason to do so.

From the comments, you mentioned you have TortoiseHG installed.  I don't know exactly how TortoiseHG works on Windows, but as Mercurial is written in Python, TortoiseHG must either come with a Python interpreter, or at least use any Python interpreter it finds on Windows (possibly using a virtualenv), so if TortoiseHG has a `PATH` entry make sure it's still after your Cygwin `{/,/usr/,/usr/local/}bin`.